# Reimplement the Double Brace Initialization of the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, anonymous-class

I have an enum `AuditType`.

And there's a map `Map<String, String>` (class field) which needs to be initialized by iterating over the `AuditType` constants and populated based on the *if-else* condition.

It has been implemented using a complicated double bracket initialization (*I haven't actually wrote this code*).

Now I'm trying to fix the Sonar's coverage because it complains that I need to use another way to initialize this map.

*Code:*

```
Map<String, String> SUBTYPES = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        Stream.of(AuditSubType.values()).forEach(auditType -> put(auditType.getCode(), auditType.name()));
    }
};
```

There is another complicated Double Brace Initialization:

```
Map<String, String> TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        Stream.of(AuditType.values()).forEach(eventType -> {
            if (AuditType.ACCOUNT_RECORD.equals(auditType)) {
                put(AuditCodes.Type.ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY.getCode(), auditType.name());
            } else {
                String ssCode = AuditCodes.Type.valueOf(auditType.name()).getCode();
                put(ssCode, auditType.name());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Sonar complaints saying *"Use another way to initialize this instance"*.

Is there a way to write it without the double bracket initialization?

Comment: Is `AuditSubType` an enum?

Comment: Yes @Eritrean Its an Enum

Comment: @user16320675 - Could you please give me a code example as to how I can use it without DBI, since I am using Stream.of

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your enum looks something like this:

```
public enum AuditSubType {
     FOO("123"),
     BAR("456"),
     BAZ("789");

     public String code;

     AuditSubType(String code){
         this.code = code;
     }
     String getCode(){
         return code;
     }
}
```

Then just use `Stream.collect(Collectors.toMap())`

```
Map<String,String> subTypes = 
       Stream.of(AuditSubType.values())
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(AuditSubType::getCode,AuditSubType::name));
```

or use `EnumSet.allOf`

```
Map<String,String> subTypes = 
       EnumSet.allOf(AuditSubType.class)
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(AuditSubType::getCode,AuditSubType::name));
```